# Event or Action bubbling in ember js

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js, ember-components

Js bin snippet here, where bubbling is not working.
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sawane/3/edit

The ember documentation says,

http://emberjs.com/guides/views/handling-events/

> Events bubble up from the target view to each parent view in succession, until the root view.

Event also bubbles through the controller and then route hierarchy.

I don't even see events being bubbled to route.

Comment: whats the question? what isnt bubbling? where does it start and where is it supposed to bubble to?

Comment: @Craicerjack check the jsbin.. also Kim gave a partial answer..

Comment: youre asking a question on stack overflow, the question and issue should really be on stackoverflow. Its great to provide a bin but not instead of a clear explanation of what you are asking. Even if I go to the bin I have to look through and try and figure out your code. Its unclear from your question whether you are trying to bubble from a view, component, or controller.

Comment: @Craicerjack bruv.. there is only one action, the action on "+" button that needs to be bubbled up to controller heirarchy..
Not sure where is the confusion.. Hope this makes clear..

Comment: okay but thats over in your code on the bin. the question is here on the flow. There isnt confusion, I'm just saying that its good practice to explain your question fully on stackoverflow. For future users, if that link ever breaks, this question would be useless, because without the bin there is no clear question.

Answer (score 0):

`Ember.Component`s are different - they don't bubble actions automatically.

In your particular case, you will have to re-send the action first in your `follow-action`-component, then again in the `user-item`-component, and then in the `user-list`-component, like so:

```
// template
{{user-list action="follow"}}

// component
...
actions: {
  follow: function() {
    this.sendAction() // The default action is 'action'
  }
}
...
```

Here is a modified jsbin which logs all the way up:
http://emberjs.jsbin.com/wobawa/1/edit

As an aside, this will be a bit easier with Ember 2.0, as it introduces some new concepts for actions in components. Check out the Ember 2.0 RFC for some more details on that.

---

Something you could do to avoid having to bubble it manually, is using the block syntax for your components to preserve the context, and then have the action in there:

```
// my-controller.hbs

// The 'follow' action will be triggered in this context (the controller)

{{#my-component}}
  {{#my-intermediate-component}}
    <button {{action 'follow'}}>Follow!</button>
  {{/my-intermediate-component}}
{{/my-component}}
```

Here is a jsbin showing this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/juzuru/1/edit

Comment: Roen: Can't I like, skip bubbling all the way through each parent component and directly bubble to route?

Modified here http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pokako/2/edit

Comment: roen: I mean is there a way to  skip defining followAction='follow' for each parent component?

Comment: Not as of right now, but it's a common question that I believe will be resolved by Ember 2.0, especially as components will be even more prominently featured.

Comment: I edited the answer with a potential solution to your specific case.